# Django Migrations every day

Tags: django, migration, django-1.7

Well i working in a software which need to receive migrations every day from an dbase database, i translate the data from dbase to json, and i save it with Django API on Postgresql, I can do it one time, but i need to do it every day,  if this process can run several times, only i need a cron process to call every day, so my cuestions are

Exists a process included in Django Migrations to solve this issue or i need implement my own solution to do it.

if exists where i can found more information about there, i read the Migration class but i not found nothing.

I was trying run the same migration several times but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you do this via a migration? If you have an API, why not just set up Celery and run your background task on an interval?

Comment: Well i was thinking the migrations because my issue is a process of migration, but you are right, maybe "Celery" can do this task, I need to check it, only i hear about it, but i don't know more about, thank you for the suggestion and i start to review it.

Comment: Migrations *can* be used to change data, but it's usually only used in the case of a schema change. Celery is easy to set up and can execute any task you need. Basically anything you do in Python can be made into a Celery task, which can be executed on an interval, and in the background. See: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html for more.

Comment: i'll see the documentation, i'm checking and is not that difficult only i need to do minor changes to it works. Thank you so much.